# how to find the frequency range in which the wave decay is possible into two parts?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

I have a question, the problem statement of which is not very understandable. It says: wave with frequency: $w_{k}=a.k^2$ Find the (frequency range) in which the (wave-decay) is possible into two parts: the first one is the same as the original wave, and the second one is by the law:$\Omega_{q}=c_{s}.q$. Does anyone have any idea what is it that is being asked here?

Many thanks!